# Could not establish connection with local server process when opening or making Unity project

Tags: unity, error-management

Whenever i try to either create or open a Unity project, I get faced with this error.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CJju.png]

Does Unity need a proxy server, because I dont have one. (If so, how do I get one?) And 
apparently I need to add some environment variables, (HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY and 
UNITY_NOPROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1) what values do i add to these?

## Unity Package Manager Diagnostics (v0.1.5)

## Ran 7 checks

1 succeeded

## 6 failed

❌ UPM registry reachable (FAIL)
Make an HTTP request to the UPM package registry

> > Connection error. This could be because a proxy is misconfigured.

❌ Ping UPM registry (FAIL)
Measure the latency of the UPM package registry API

> > No successful pings could be made in 0.062 seconds (30 failed)

❌ Ping UPM download (FAIL)
Measure the latency of the UPM package download endpoint

> > No successful pings could be made in 0.039 seconds (30 failed)

❌ UPM registry download speed (FAIL)
Test the Internet connection using the UPM package registry

> > Connection error. This could be because a proxy is misconfigured.

❌ Speedtest.net (FAIL)
Test the Internet connection using Speedtest.net

> > Connection error. This could be because a proxy is misconfigured.

✅ HTTP proxy environment variables (PASS)
Detect whether proxy-related environment variables are set (HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY, ALL_PROXY, NO_PROXY, UNITY_PROXYSERVER, UNITY_NOPROXY)

> > Proxy support has been configured through the following environment variables:
> >     HTTPS_PROXY = C:\Program Files\Unity Hub\Unity Hub.exe
> >     HTTP_PROXY = C:\Program Files\Unity Hub\Unity Hub.exe
> >     UNITY_NOPROXY = C:\Program Files\Unity Hub\Unity Hub.exe

❌ UPM health check (FAIL)
Start the UPM process and call its health endpoint

> > Server started but did not respond to health requests:
> >     Error: Invalid protocol: c:

How do I fix this?

Comment: What Unity version are you using? Have you tried the solutions [listed here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/could-not-establish-a-connection-with-the-unity-package-manager-local-server-process.746267/#:~:text=%5BPackage%20Manager%5DCould%20not%20establish%20a%20connection%20with%20the%20Unity,%2FHub%2FEditor%2F2019.2.)?

Comment: I've tried setting up environment variables for both the package manager exe and the unity hub exe, but it didn't work. I also don't know how exactly to allow certain domains through the whitelist, and google didn't help. I also don't exactly know if unity does need a proxy server or not, and looking up how to get one didn't help. I just ran the Speedtest.net test, and my pings per second are 19 pings, and my download mps was 3.32, and upload mps was 6.99 mps. Nothing worked.

Comment: This is trying to access a process on your own PC, so ping is not relevant here. You have some rule on your computer blocking communication between processes over http.

Comment: I have finally found the source of my problem. By turning off the firewall, i can access unity again, which means that the problem was about something being blocked in the firewall. Now I can properly fix the problem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you've solved your firewall problem, I recommend posting the steps you took to solve it as an Answer below, to help other users with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, checked 127.0.0.1 on my browser and got an error hence  setx UNITY_NOPROXY localhost did not work for me, so I went to my windows defender firewall with advanced security,  and turned off the domain ,public and private profiles since I already have Quick Heal on, and my project started working, I suppose there was a conflict between Quick Heal and Windows Defender as both of them were turned on! I hope that helps!

Comment: You can also tweak the rules for Unity alone, rather than opening up your firewall completely.